# Strange knockout binding result. With gives result, while dotting does not

Tags: knockout.js

Given the following code. Why is "test" replaced with "" while "test2" is replaced with "Travel Log"

```
    <h1 id="mainHeader" data-bind="text: $root.localization.frontHeader">test</h1>
    <div id="pages" data-bind="with: localization">
        <h1 class="frontHeader" data-bind="text: frontHeader">test2</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with the solution for the Cannot read property 'frontHeader' of undefined  problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `localization` property is a `ko.observable` then you need to write `localization()` if you're using it inside an expression.

So change your binding to :

```
<h1 id="mainHeader" data-bind="text: $root.localization().frontHeader">test</h1>
<div id="pages" data-bind="with: localization">
    <h1 class="frontHeader" data-bind="text: frontHeader">test2</h1>
</div>
```

But in this case you need to handle that case when your `localization` property is empty (the `with` binding does this for you).

So to make it work for the case when your  `localization` property is empty (or null or undefined) then you need to add an extra check in your binding:

```
<h1 id="mainHeader" 
    data-bind="text: $root.localization() && $root.localization().frontHeader">
       test
</h1>
<div id="pages" data-bind="with: localization">
    <h1 class="frontHeader" data-bind="text: frontHeader">test2</h1>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPbkX/).

Answer (score 0):

`"with"` does the invocation of an observable for you.
Inside an expression, you need to invoke it yourself, hence you need to add "()". `data-bind="text: $root.localization().frontHeader"`

Comment: This gives me the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: text: $root.localization().frontHeader
Message: Cannot read property 'frontHeader' of undefined